# Arquivos deletados Django Migrations

Tags: django, migrations

Estou tendo um problema constante. Como estou trabalhando com diversas branchs em um projeto, as vezes volto em uma branch antiga, trago branch atualizada para a antiga para nao ter que ficar criando migration de banco antigo. So que toda vez da problema com migrations. As vezes da um erro absurdo e eu deleto tudo, os migrations, a base e recomeco. Isso funciona, so que ai os arquivos do migration ficam diferentes. Entao quando vou fazer migrate da erro pois esta faltando arquivo ou dependencia.

Gostaria de entender o processo que tenho que fazer para evitar ou resolver esses problemas. Lembrando que tenho um ambiente em producao, que mesmo nao disponivel para o usuario, provavelmente pode acontecer esse tipo de problema.

No meu caso o problema é esse:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration comunidade.0011_auto_20170608_1556 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('comunidade', '0010_auto_20170605_1809')
```

Quando entro no arquivo, ele tem uma dependencia para o arquivo:

```
0010_auto_20170605_1809
```

Porem nao tem esse arquivo. Pois provavelmente foi deletado ou coisa do tipo. Eu poderia tentar mudar manualmente para o ultimo arquivo, o `0002_auto_20170621_1721`. Porém, ele tem a validacao no banco, acho que nao e o ideal.

Eu tentei fazer o migrate zero, mas o erro continua dando. Fiz um --fake (que ja me falaram que é porco) e nada.

Preciso de alguma dica. Estou usando **Django 1.10 e Python 3.4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problemas com migrations é bem comum no universo django, ja vi relatos que em cenarios complexos algumas equipes preferem criar mecanismos para desabilitar as migrações. Depois de algum tempo de "sofrimento" e muita pesquisa na intenet, acabei criando um script para "resetar" as migrações, vou reproduzir os passos abaixo (meu ambiente é o linux):

1) Limpe o histórico para todas as apps, o exemplo abaixo limpa o histórico da app de nome core.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake core zero
```

2) Remova os arquivos de migração:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

3) Crie as migrações iniciais:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

Agora dê um showmigrations e veja que tudo está ok.

Minha estrategia:
Coloquei esse comandos em um arquivo e executo-o todas as vezes que faço um deploy, uma copia da producção para o staging ou do staging para o local.

Comment: Se vc mantem o banco de produção sempre sincronizado com o de trabalho (integração continua) isso não é problema.